# Selectize select default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, selectize.js

I have some problem with javascript/jQuery using Selectize.js

```
$sel_professione;

$(document).ready(function() {

$sel_professione = $('#professioneCliente').selectize({
        delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
        create: function(input) {
        return {
                value: input,
                text: input
            }
    }
});

$(document).on("click", "#b_Modifica", function() {
    $sel_professione.addOption({value:13,text:'foo'});
    $sel_professione.selectize.addItem(13); 

$('#aggiungiCliente').modal('show');
});
```

When I try to modify `$sel_professione` from the `onClick` function I get an error from the javascript console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionclienti.js:301
>   (anonymous function)jquery.js:3 m.event.dispatchjquery.js:3
>   m.event.add.r.handle

I tried to move my `onclick` function inside the `$.ready`, but nothing changed.

Some advice?

Thanks all for the support that everytime you give me on this site :)

Comment: add var before $sel_professione;  like var $sel_professione;

Comment: also which version of jquery you use?

Comment: Added var, still same problem:
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionclienti.js:314 (anonymous function)jquery.js:3 m.event.dispatchjquery.js:3 m.event.add.r.handle`

Jquery v1.11.1 at the moment, never had any problem

Comment: is it possible to create fiddle ?

Comment: never done a fiddle before, I'll try

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem using:

```
$sel_professione[0].selectize.addOption({value:13,text:'foo'}); //option can be created manually or loaded using Ajax
$sel_professione[0].selectize.addItem(13);
```

Instead of:

```
 $sel_professione.addOption({value:13,text:'foo'});
$sel_professione.selectize.addItem(13);
```

Found the answer here: 
[selectize.js/examples/api.html](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/api.html)